# Is there a reusable convenience function to update a ManyToManyField's value without clearing it first?

Tags: django

Looking at the Django source, I see that on assignment to a ManyToManyField, all existing values are removed before the new values are added:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L776

That naive algorithm will introduce tremendous database churn when my application runs—it updates hundreds of thousands of such relationships at a time.

Since, in my case, most of these updates will be noops (i.e., the current and new values will be identical), I could easily reduce churn by updating the M2M field with an algorithm where I first check which objects need to be added, and then check which need to be removed.

This seems like such a common pattern that I'm wondering if a reusable function to do this already exists?

Comment: But if you are *assigning* to a many2many field is like saying "Remove any pre-existing entries and add this one". Otherwise you would use the `add` method. Correct?

Comment: In my application, most of the time the pre-existing and the new values will be the same, or mostly the same—maybe one new value will be added, or one will have been removed. I'm sure it's a common problem: I way to make list A look like list B without first deleting all elements in list A and then adding all elements in list B.

Comment: Then the bitwise overloaded operators (& and |) on querysets, might be of help for implementing what you need.